# Intersect associative array from another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, search, intersect

I have two array that is

```
$a = array( 
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => "Facebook" 
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => "Twitter" 
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => "Google" 
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => "Linkdin" 
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => "Github" 
    ),
);
```

And another is,

```
$b = array(1, 3, 5);
```

According to the $b array value, $a associative array id will be selected as result. 
[image: intersect two array]
So the result will be,

```
$result = $a = array( 
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => "Facebook" 
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => "Google" 
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => "Github" 
    ),
);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Dupe of [simply using array_uintersect()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321591/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple oneliner (more readable with 4 lines though):

```
$result = array_filter(
    $a, 
    function($v) use ($b) { return in_array($v['id'], $b); }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value['id'], $b)) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way computing the intersection:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_column($a, null, 'id'), array_flip($b));
```

- Reindex `$a` by `id`
- Flip `$b` to get values as keys
- Compute the intersection of the keys