# Filter an array of objects to keep objects with a specific property value found in a flat, whitelist array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, intersection, whitelist

I have this multidimensional array `$currencies`:

```
$currencies = array ( 
    0 => (object) array( 'name' => 'algo', 'fullName' => 'Algorand'), 
    1 => (object) array( 'name' => 'ardr', 'fullName' => 'Ardor'), 
    2 => (object) array( 'name' => 'eth', 'fullName' => 'Eth')
);
```

And I want to keep only the objects with a `name` that is in this array:

```
$filter = ["eth", "algo"];
```

I did this, but it doesn't work.

```
$currenciesFiltered = array_filter(
    $currencies,
    function ($value) use ($filter) {
        return in_array($value['name'], $filter);
    }
);
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't see any mistakes. Please show your array $currencies in PHP notation (as output var_export ($ currencies)).

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Is any error thrown? Maybe it's because you used an object of type `stdClass` as array? `return in_array($value->name, $filter)`

Comment: @jspit i did it. Maybe it's because of the (object) ? What do you think about this ?

Comment: Easy enough to take away the `(object)` casting and see if it works...

Comment: @MihaiMatei sounds good what you said. I this this error : Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: It works with `$value->name`, with the code you have shown us. If it doesn’t work with what you have - then something must be significantly different, from what you have shown.

Comment: Same task, different data-type: [Keep array rows where a column value is found in a second flat array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47503473/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error output:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in [...][...]:13
```

You are casting the array to an object, but then trying to use it as an array later. When you remove the `(object)` casting, it works just as you are expecting.

If you must cast to an object, do it *after* the filter.

Comment: Thanks Jake, i didn't find out the first time there is an object inside.  It's when i saw the replies of jspit and Minhai Matei
So i did this just before doing the filter
 foreach($currencies as $key => $currency){
            $currencies[$key] = (array) $currency;
        }

Comment: More simple : 

Use : $value->name, $filter);

Answer (score 1):

PHP already has native, optimized functions to compare/filter data from two iterable datasets.

`array_uintersect()`, in this case is perfect for filtering based on value.

Because the source array(s) that populate the `$a` and `$b` variable during iteration cannot be predicted, each attempt to access data must fallback to the alternate array's data.

Because only the `$currencies` array contains rows of objects, check for a `name` property inside the callback. If the property does not exist, you know that the accessible value belongs to the flat `$filter` array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AjIrN))

```
var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $currencies,
        $filter,
        fn($a, $b) =>
            ($a->name ?? $a)
            <=>
            ($b->name ?? $b)
    )
);
```

The above has the same effect as making iterated `in_array()` calls inside of `array_filter()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/BJcSX)

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $currencies,
        fn($obj) => in_array($obj->name, $filter)
    )
);
```

Both techniques output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'name' => 'algo',
     'fullName' => 'Algorand',
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'name' => 'eth',
     'fullName' => 'Eth',
  ),
)
```